# How handle Multiple Type convertor exception in CSVhelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Recently I upgraded CSVHelper libraries from 2.7.1 to 30 version.
I have resolved all build errors. But after upgradation exceptions are not logging.
Old Code:

```
csvReader.Configuration.ReadingExceptionCallback =
                        (ex, row) =>
                        {
                            if (ex is CsvHelper.TypeConversion.CsvTypeConverterException)
                            {
                                foreach (DictionaryEntry error in ex.Data)
                                {
                                    AddRowError(row.Row, error.Value.ToString() + " Column Name: '" + GetColumnName(row) + "'");
                                }
                            }
                            else if (ex is FormatException)
                            {
                                AddRowError(row.Row, ex.Message + " Column Name: '" + GetColumnName(row) + "' Column Value: '" + GetColumnValue(row) + "'");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                AddRowError(row.Row, string.Format("Line[{0}]: {1}", row.Row, ex.StackTrace));
                            }

                        };
```

New Code:

```
ReadingExceptionOccurred = args =>
                        {
                            var context = args.Exception.Context;
                            if (args.Exception is CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterException)
                            {
                                foreach (DictionaryEntry error in args.Exception.Data)
                                {
                                    AddRowError(context.Parser.Row, error.Value.ToString() + " Column Name: '" + GetColumnName(context.Reader) + "'");
                                }
                            }
                            else if (args.Exception.GetType() == typeof(FormatException))
                            {
                                AddRowError(context.Parser.Row, args.Exception.Message + " Column Name: '" + GetColumnName(context.Reader) + "' Column Value: '" + GetColumnValue(context.Reader) + "'");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                AddRowError(context.Parser.Row, string.Format("Line[{0}]: {1}", context.Parser.Row, args.Exception.StackTrace));
                            }
                            return false;
                        },
```

1)how to handle ex.Data?
I had written as args.Exception.Data. But in data I do not see any key value pair as previous.

2. ex is FormatException
   How to handle FormatException

[image]

Comment: *1)how to handle ex.Data?* -- I don't know what was there before but according to the [change log](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/change-log/) in 6.0 they *Added more info and properties to TypeConverterException.*  Maybe that's what you need?  From the [source code for TypeConverterException](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/TypeConversion/TypeConverterException.cs) I see properties like `MemberMapData`, `Text`, `TypeConverter` and so on.

Comment: It seems that I have to remove for loop

Comment: Do you have an example where CsvHelper throws a `FormatException` in Version 2.7.1?  I haven't been able to create that exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `args.Exception.Message`.  It gives the same information (plus some) as looping through `ex.Data`.

looping through `ex.Data` in Version 2.7.1

```
4: Row: '4' (1 based)
Type: 'UserQuery+Foo'
Field Index: '0' (0 based)
Field Name: 'Id'
Field Value: 'three'
```

`args.Exception.Message` in Version 30.0.1

```
The conversion cannot be performed.
    Text: 'three'
    MemberName: Id
    MemberType: System.Int32
    TypeConverter: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.Int32Converter'
IReader state:
   ColumnCount: 0
   CurrentIndex: 0
   HeaderRecord:
["Id","Name"]
IParser state:
   ByteCount: 0
   CharCount: 30
   Row: 4
   RawRow: 4
   Count: 2
   RawRecord:
three,name3
```